# How to pass file path from C# application to Python script and return the processed file path back to C#?In Visual Studio

Tags: python, c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

**This question is in regards to the references or some other similar feature in Visual Studio 2019. Both my C# and Python projects are part of a single solution**

I am developing a C# application using WPF that requires running Python scripts in the backend to perform specific operations on user-selected files. Due to strict dependencies on pandas, I cannot use IronPython, and I want to avoid using PYQt to avoid license fees since I plan to sell the program.

I have created two projects: one in C# and the other in Python. The C# application will have a GUI with buttons for different tasks. When a button is clicked, the user can select a file, and the C# application should pass the file path to the Python script as an argument. The Python script will process the file and return the processed file path back to the C# application. Finally, the C# application will prompt the user to save the generated file.

I am looking for a way to accomplish this communication between the two projects. How can I pass the file path from the C# application to the Python script and retrieve the processed file path back in the C# application? What is the best way to handle the communication between the two projects to ensure efficient and reliable operation?

Please provide sample code or relevant resources to help me achieve this functionality in my C# application.

[image]

[image]

I tried few things like IronPython and PythonNet. But I feel running a Python Project through the C# GUI would be the best thing. I can't say how complicated the next item in the grid may be. I may require a third language.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate a Python project into a C# project, I moved the Python code to the same project directory and set up paths to access the required files. I used paths like `string columnsFilePath = Path.Combine("./columns.txt");` and manually put the Python embedded and other required files to the "Release" directory after building the exe using C#.

Using embedded Python enhanced the functionality of the application by allowing us to leverage the strengths of both Python and C#. The process of adding Python embedded to the project folder and setting up paths was straightforward and involved copying the Python code and libraries to the project directory and specifying the paths to access the required files.

To build the exe using C#, I used the appropriate tools and libraries, and the process was straightforward. However, I had to manually copy the Python embedded, images, and columns.txt file to the release folder since they were not included in the automated build process.

Overall, integrating Python into a C# project using embedded Python allowed us to enhance the functionality of the application and leverage the strengths of both languages.

Steps to install packages into the Python Embedded:

1. Download `get-pip.py` from google.
2. Unzip the Python Embedded and paste `get-pip.py` into the Python Embedded folder.
3. Uncomment import in `python310._pth`
4. Run `./path/to/python.exe get-pip.py`.
5. Run `./path/to/python.exe pip install package_name`.

[Link to Python Embedded](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3113/)

[image]